# Hover on image makes 2 elements appear

Tags: css, hover, centering

My main question is how to make 2 elements appear when hovering on an image.

Code produces:[image: Code results. See the snippet below for more details.]
The blue div is covering more space than it's half of 2 columns on hover. I think its because the span is taking up space on static not hover mode. Also, span is not horizontally centered inside the blue div despite the `align-items:center` on the container div.

```css
.main {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 15px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 15px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 15px;
}

.rollover {
  background-color: white;
}

.layer {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.rollover:hover .layer {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.layer span {
  display: none;
  color: black;
}

.layer:hover span {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
}

.rollover:hover img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column rollover">
        <div class="layer"><img src="https://img.creator-prod.zmags.com/assets/images/648afc28b6fc7c5ba75cf2ab.jpeg?im=Resize,width=768"><span>The Alex</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column"><img src="https://img.creator-prod.zmags.com/assets/images/648afc28b6fc7c5ba75cf2ab.jpeg?im=Resize,width=768"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: HTML and a snippet would help a lot here to avoid guessing and provide better solutions

Comment: Currently your HTML is just an image OR bad CSS/malformed at that...please edit to a snippet
re: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: I edited to take the malformed HTML and css and make a snippet however there are not "The blue div is covering more space than it's half of 2 columns on hover" two columns.

Comment: Sorry I just updated the code. It is inside 2 columns now.

Comment: Why not edit the snippet instead of removing it?  re: scroll down to the Stack Snippets link here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: created a new snippet

Comment: I formatted your snippets code - but maybe we don't need both now?

Comment: Im sorry mark, which snippet did you format? I just erased the top snippet. Im sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: It's all good, I formatted both but did not know which might be your preferred version that clearly reproduces your issue.

Comment: OK if we just remove the code part NOT in the snippet now perhaps to make this even better?  Up to you there as it is your question; just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes I removed the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the two elements at same place so we can use a grid then put them both at that same row/column 1.

Reset to some basics at first.

Remove a bit of CSS.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /*  viewportunits to cover page fully */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

* {
  /* include border and padding in element width and height */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 1rem;
  border: solid #00FF00 1px;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  place-items: center;
}

.column.rollover .layer>* {
  grid: 1/1;
}

.row img {
  width: 100%;
}

.layer {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.layer span {
  display: none;
}

.rollover:hover .layer span {
  display: block;
}

.rollover:hover .layer img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column rollover">
        <div class="layer"><img src="https://img.creator-prod.zmags.com/assets/images/648afc28b6fc7c5ba75cf2ab.jpeg?im=Resize,width=768"><span>The Alex</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column"><img src="https://img.creator-prod.zmags.com/assets/images/648afc28b6fc7c5ba75cf2ab.jpeg?im=Resize,width=768"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I made this flow a bit better depending on view size for a better demo.